# jquery datepicker formatting

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to format a jquery datepicker to display as Saturday, 18 May, 2013 but also have a second hidden field that would submit 2013-05-18 so I can use it in a MySQL query. I cannot seem to get it to work right. It keeps displaying as 05/18/2013. Here is my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  altField: "#alt-datepicker",
  altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  format: "DD, MM d, yy"
});
});
</script>



Date: <input type='text' id='datepicker' placeholder='Date'/><br />
<input type='hidden' id='alt-datepicker' name='AddHomeworkDate' />
```

Comment: Can you please see this - http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

READ MORE [**DATEPICKER**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Datepicker&redirect=no#option-dateFormat)

Comment: was too late to post this answer, but +1 to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Comment: You need not to put .val()

Comment: Ok @sasi,iam just suggesting,thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you already got date value - like - 6/09/07

```
var cur_date = '6/09/07';
dateFormat(cur_date, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

It will give you output - Sat Jun 09 2007 17:46:22

see this http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You did small mistake in **dateFormat** insted simply **format**
Here is the solution check this fiddel jsfiddle.net/2e8qE/

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine;

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      altField: "#alt-datepicker",
      altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy"
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8s7d6/)